# Need help fixing this C++ code (Quadratic Formula solver)

Tags: c++

When I execute the problem, the results often end up as "-nan' or "nan"
I am new to programming so this is a bit confusing. Could use some help

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


//Quadratic Equation
int main() {

 //Variables
 double a,b,c,n,z,x1,x2,r;    

 //Input
 cout<<"Quadartic Equation Calculator"<<endl<<endl;     
 cout<<"What is you 'a' value?: "<<endl;
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"What is your 'b' value?:  "<<endl;
 cin>>b;
 cout<<"What is your 'c' value?:  "<<endl;  
 cin>>c;  

 //calculation
  n = -b;
  z = sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c));
  r= 2*a;
  x1 = (n+(z))/r;
  x2 = (n-(z))/r;

//output
 cout<<"Your Solutions are:  "<< x1 << " or "<< x2;

 return 0;             
 }
```

`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you say *the results often end up as "-nan' or "nan"*, please realize that we can be helped greatly when you provide the a, b, and c that you used as input. And just a hint -- *nan* means Not a Number, such as what you get when you take the square root of a negative number.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::sqrt()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) in the `<cmath>` header expects its argument to be a positive number, in case it isn't, it will return `nan` which is what you are facing. It also raises the `FE_INVALID` floating point exception which you can verify after calling the `std::sqrt()` function using [`std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/fetestexcept).

In actual math, square roots of negative numbers result in [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). Ordinary floating-point types like `double` which *usually* follow the [IEEE-754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) are not capable of representing complex numbers. For that, you need to use something like [`std::complex<double>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) which is actually capable of storing complex numbers inside it.

Below is your code modified to utilize `std::complex<double>` and will properly print the real and imaginary part separately for square roots of negative real numbers instead of simply returning `nan` as it did before.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

double abs_zero(double const x) {
    return x == 0 ? 0 : x;
}

int main() {
    // Variables
    complex<double> a, b, c, n, z, x1, x2, r;

    // Input
    cout << "Quadartic Equation Calculator" << endl << endl;
    cout << "What is your 'a' value?: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "What is your 'b' value?: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "What is your 'c' value?: " << endl;
    cin >> c;

    // Calculation
    n = -b;
    z = sqrt((b * b) - (complex<double>(4, 0) * a * c));
    r = complex<double>(2, 0) * a;
    x1 = (n + z) / r;
    x2 = (n - z) / r;

    x1 = complex<double>(abs_zero(real(x1)), abs_zero(imag(x1)));
    x2 = complex<double>(abs_zero(real(x2)), abs_zero(imag(x2)));

    // Output
    if (imag(x1) == 0)
        cout << "Your Solutions are: " << real(x1) << " or "<< real(x2) << endl;
    else
        cout << "Your Solutions are: " << x1 << " or " << x2 << endl;
}
```

In case you'd like to try it out yourself, here you are:

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/14KKee49K)

Answer (score 1):

NAN is in short for "Not a Number" is an exception which usually occurs in the cases when a number can’t be represented. Its probably that **sqrt((bxb)-(4*a*c))** is causing the error as for some inputs the square root of that input would be undefined. For example in case of a = 5, b = 4 and c = 3, sqrt((bxb)-(4*a*c)) is undefined as it is sqrt. of negative number.

Answer (score 0):

"Often" end up as nan or -nan? That's expected behaviour. The quadratic formula gives you the roots of the equation, where the graph intersects the x-axis. Not all quadratic equations intersect the x-axis.

When you input a quadratic that doesn't intersect the x-axis into the quadratic formula, you end up with a negative number in the square-root of the equation, which leads to an imaginary number, which cannot be represented by the `float`/`double` data type, and thus you get "nan" or "-nan".